# Tools to compile pointers to arrays of static size

Tags: c

Are there any static code analyzing tools for C that convert pointers to arrays of a static size? It is a marginal pain and I just figured I'd check with the community. A quick google search did not turn up anything useful because "to" in the phrase "pointer to array" generally means something completely different from what I'm looking for here... Any suggestions or keywords would be helpful.

P.s. I'm trying to convert some code into synthesizable C for a hardware implementation.

So for instance, this code is not synthesizable:

```
void sum(float *a, int size, float *out) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        *out += a+1;
}
```

It is not synthesizable since the size of a is not statically declared at runtime. (Note, that out should be ok since it is not an array - though I'm not 100% sure on that.) It would be lovely if there was a tool to convert use of variable sized arrays to arrays whose sizes were known at compile time.

Furthermore, this code must be transformed (currently manually) to something like this:

```
// Not 100% sure if float * is still allowed.
void sum(float a[SIZE], float *out) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        *out += a[i]; // Not sure if this is necessary.
}
```

Right now, I would have to do this manually. I have to resolve all usages of dynamic arrays. This is how HLS works. It is a serious issue. It is hard (or at least time-consuming) to do when you did not write the original code. It must be converted so that you can synthesize the code to hardware.

All array sizes must be resolved - they may not have been explicitly declared initially. Then these array sizes must be propagated to all affected functions/references.

Finally, for those of you confused by "synthesizable", feel free to check out these two links that describe it much better than I can...

http://www.cse.psu.edu/~xydong/files/proceedings/DAC2010/data/1964-2006_papers/PAPERS/1988/DAC88_330.PDF
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/ug998-vivado-intro-fpga-design-hls.pdf

Comment: "convert pointers to arrays of a static size" Huh? Convert to what? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Would this perhaps be better asked / answered on StackOverflow?

Comment: Perhaps, but it has to do with High Level Synthesis... Neither Stack nor EE has an HLS tag. Since software developers don't usually think about HLS I figured there might be a group here who understand the (common!) issue I'm having. But yes, I will post it to SO as well.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810083/c-pointers-pointing-to-an-array-of-fixed-size) could be what you're looking for; That link shows how you can pass pointers to memory of constant size.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about source code analysis and transformation.

Comment: @Kaz, I'm not <i>trying</i> to do anything other than get a headstart on this issue. I'd appreciate any assistance in relocating the topic or anything else. Telling me the question is off-topic is not super helpful.

Comment: @phileaton I would say, the `comp.compilers` or `comp.lang.misc` Usenet newsgroups, maybe.

Comment: None of the function arguments are arrays; they are pointers. There isn't an array declaration to be seen in the code snippet. In C, you cannot pass arrays into functions or return them from functions, unless they are wrapped in a `struct`,e.g. `struct fixedarray { float a[32]; }`. This `struct` can be passed and returned by value.

Comment: I think you mean a+i, no??  In any case, the subroutine uses a pointer to a float and a float.  There is no storage of the entire array in this subroutine.  It doesn't need to store the whole array it acts on.  I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Kaz, I think he wants to pass pointer of a constant size (at compile-time). Check out the link I posted above, there are some interesting ways to do exactly what he asks (at least my interpretation thereof). As for the *synthesization* referred to I am unsure.

Comment: @sherrellbc et al, I updated my question with a couple of links that might illustrate what I mean by synthesis. However, I'm still at a loss for the name of what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: The declaration `float a[SIZE]` still declares a pointer if `a` is a function argument. ISO C requires the declaration to satisfy constraint rules pertaining to arrays (so for instance a diagnostic is required if `SIZE` is present, and isn't a positive integer). After that, `a` becomes a "pointer to float".  We see this often in `main` which can be declared as `int main(int c, char **v)` or, equivalently, `int main(int c, char *v[])`.

Comment: Use a more suitable language in the first place.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, as much as I'd like to write FPGA logic in Verilog I think I would rather do it in C and have someone translate it for me. That is like avoiding python because you don't have access to pointers to scalar types. It's not wrong, there's just a different way to do what you want. And you use it because it's higher level than C. Same thing here.

Comment: I would use a higher level language than C too. But agreed you may not have the choice, C/C++ is everywhere, despite its unsuitability.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare an array of fixed size and then access it using a pointer,
take for instance you can declare

```
float a[10];
```

and access it as

```
*(a+index)= <value>;
```

*a representing a[0].

for your sum function, you can leave the following function intact

```
`    void sum(float *a, int size, float *out) {
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++)
            *out += a+1;
    }
```

and make changes in the calling program
preprocessor directive

```
#define size <yourchoice>
```

variable declaration

```
float a[size];
float out[size];
```

function call

```
sum((float*)a,int size,(float*)out);
```

m not sure what your function is trying to achieve block addition or sum of consecutive floats...but hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In C you don't pass arrays by value to functions, instead you just pass the pointer, ie an address of a memory location that act as a valid storage for your data. This is the reason some trick has to be used to pass the size ( ie the number of elements accessible ). This is usually called as a "by ref" parameter passing in some higher level languages. In your question you seems almost ignore the `*out` pointer. Indeed is important that the caller pass a pointer to a valid memory portion wide at least `size*sizeof(float)` bytes. Note than a `+1` on a `float *` means a `sizeof(float)` increment to the absolute value of the address  (usually `4` bytes). Don't know if this is the answer you want, but this is the essence of `C`, the fact that makes `C` an usually fast language.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the general case.

It *might* be possible in your specific case, writing a tool that takes the first declaration of an array and forces that size on called functions. But what if a function is called with arrays of different or variable sizes?

In general C-to-Verilog produces poor results, especially with code that wasn't written to be retargeted. How large is the code you're trying to target, and what roughly does it do?